# How to extract views from Razor class libraries?

Tags: asp.net-core

When you add `Identity` to your ASP.NET Core applications, you can **scaffold** its Razor pages.

[image]

I am looking for a way to **extract** my views **from a referenced RCL** just like `Identity`.

I mean I want to create Area and related files (cshtml) to help developers to customize it (not a specific UI as you see in the above pic).

Do there exist any command-line tools to a way to extract Razor pages (.cshtml)?

I checked inside of a Razor class library with `dotpeek` there is no HTML resource, everything is class.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: At present, I didn't find a tool to extract Razor pages as you described. From the [official RCL document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets), the RCL can be referenced by NuGet package and {ProjectName}.csproj. I suggest you could feedback this issue to [Asp.net core github  discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues).

Comment: OP created issue [RCL scaffold tool](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27110) in ASP.NET Core repo that was answered.